# Extracting columns from many files of variable lengths to a new file with headers

Tags: bash, unix, awk, command-line

I have 100's of files with the same number of columns, but a different number of rows. I want to take the second column of all the files and combine them into a new file. I've tried using:

`awk '{ a[FNR] = (a[FNR] ? a[FNR] FS : "") $2 } END { for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i] }' $(ls -1v *)  > collapsed_output.csv`

But for some reason this limits all columns to the length of the smallest one (so you lose a lot of data).

In the new file I'd also like each column to be labelled with its original file name.

[A sample input/desired output might be this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4MTn.png)

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code, could you please do mention samples of input and expected output in your question(in brief manner) so that we get better idea of your question, thank you.

Comment: `$(ls -1v *)` just `*`. `*` is already the list of files, it's like `ls -1v $(ls -1v $(ls -1v *)))`, it's going to be the same. `awk '....' *`

Comment: Your `END` block uses the `FNR` value from the last file.  You want to iterate over the maximum `FNR` value that was ever seen, I think.